# Are there good breakdowns of world's immigration systems by main parameters?

Tags: immigration

Seeing a side discussion about Australian vs. UK immigration system, I grew curious as to how popular are different models of immigration systems around the world.

I'm looking for a good compiled data on how popular specific features are among the countries, including the following typical categories:

- Limited vs. Unlimited (e.g. is the # of immigrants capped; and how large is it compared to present population)
- Degree of selectivity (e.g. are people with needed skills prioritized generally or exclusively) (*this one is harder to score/evaluate since for example USA has a hybrid system where some spots are reserved for skills based visas and some for no-requirements-based visas*)

Comment: I don't know that the US has any "no requirements" immigration.  The US is noteworthy for accepting family reunification as an uncommonly large fraction of its overall immigration.  But "related to a citizen" is, in and of itself, a requirement.

Comment: @Brythan - Yeah, as I said, US has a hybrid and some fractions match all different patterns.

Comment: @Brythan what about the green card lottery?